# How to add lines containing numbers from a folder line by line with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, math, txt

I need exactly the following actions by Python:

1. Open the folder.
2. Finding files with ".txt" format
3. Open the found files.
4. Reading a line from each file and adding numbers.
5. Perform step 4 until the end of the files (5 lines).
6. Dividing the obtained numbers by the number of opened files (Getting a grade point average).
7. Write the result in the "finish.txt" file in the same folder.

I wrote a code but it doesn't work. if you can fix it please do.
Also you can solve my problem by another code.

```
import os
path = str(os.path.dirname(__file__))+"\\files"
os.chdir(path)
def sl (fp):
    path = str(os.path.dirname(__file__))+"\\files"
    L=len([name for name in os.listdir(path) if 
os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, name))])
    if L:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            Length=L
        else:
            Length=1
    finish=open(os.path.dirname(__file__)+"\\finish.txt", 
"w")
    Sum1=0
    Sum2=0
    Sum3=0
    Sum4=0
    Sum5=0
    with open(file_path, 'r') as fp:
        line_numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
        lines = []
        for i, line in enumerate(fp):
            if i in line_numbers:
                lines.append(line.strip())
                if i==0:
                    Sum1+=int(line)
                if i==1:
                    Sum2+=int(line)
                if i==2:
                    Sum3+=int(line)
                if i==3:
                    Sum4+=int(line)
                if i==4:
                    Sum5+=int(line)
            elif i > 4:
                break
        Write=str(int(Sum1/Length))+"\n"+str(int(Sum2/Length))+"\n"+str(int(Sum3/Length))+"\n"+str(int(Sum4/Length))+"\n"+str(int(Sum5/Length))+"\n"

finish.write(Write+str((Sum1+Sum2+Sum3+Sum4+Sum5)/Length))
        finish.close()
    # iterate through all file
    for file in os.listdir():
    # Check whether file is in text format or not
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        file_path = f"{path}\{file}"
        sl(file_path)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  Do you want the average of all of the line 1s, and then the average of all of the line 2s, and then the average of all of the line 3s, etc?  If so, then you have to gather up the sums over ALL the files.  You can't print any results until you have read every file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, as I described, the average of all of the line 1s, and the average of all of the line 2s, etc, then this will do it.

Note that it is not necessary to specify a path each time, since you use `chdir` to make that the current directory.  Note that I keep all of the sums in a list.  ANY TIME you find your self using variables called `xxx1`, `xxx2`, `xxx3` etc, you need to replace that set with a list.  Finally, note that I wait until all the files have been read before computing the results.

```
import os
path = str(os.path.dirname(__file__))+"\\files"
os.chdir(path)

sums = [0,0,0,0,0]
count = 0

for name in os.listdir('.'):
    if name.endswith(".txt"):
        count += 1
        for num, line in enumerate(open(name, 'r')):
            if num > 4:
                break
            sums[num] += float(line.strip())

finish = open("finish.txt",'w')
for i in sums:
    print( i/count, file=finish)
print(sum(sums) / count, file=finish)
finish.close()
```

Comment: This code has some bugs that I tried to fix. But Thank you for your kindness and sharing your knowledge.
This is the solved partes:

In line 11:
  for num, line in enumerate(open(name, 'r')):
Because if you don't use from enumerate, it gaves the ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) Error.

In line 14:

   sums[num] += float(line.strip()) 
Because if the number is Integer it makes error. (averages are usually a float, not an int).

I thank you again for solving my problem. I appreciate you for sharing your knowledge.